# zf2 automated translation for dynamic strings

Tags: zend-framework2

I am working on zf2 translation.I have added some fields in database,I added translated string for each field for each language.

But User can also add field.Suppose user is in English local and added A field in English language only,But later some user accessed the website and he or she knows Spanish,In this case for this user that field which previous user added should displayed in Spanish language.

So in this case how to manage dynamic field translation.Can any one help me for this issue.

Comment: You need a translation API to translate the words when entered by the user, have a look at [Googles Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/)

Comment: Retrieve the fields from your database and build the PHP array for the Translator ArrayAdapter for each language?